# How can I join a table to itself having it look like it's three tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Honestly, I don't know how to join a table to itself to solve this problem.

I have a table that stored it's record in the format below:
[image]

I want to query the table and display it's record in this format:
[image]

This is what I have tried so far

```
Select f.score as first_term, s.score as second_term, t.score as term_tetm from table f left join table s left join table t using (studentid) where studentid = 001 group by subject
```

Comment: Search for the term `pivot` in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result by grouping on the subject name, but then you will have to use an aggregate function. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #StudentGrades  
(
    [SUBJECT]       VARCHAR(50),  
    [STUDENT_ID]    VARCHAR(3),  
    [SCORE]         INT,  
    [TERM]          VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #StudentGrades ([SUBJECT], [STUDENT_ID],[SCORE],[TERM])
VALUES  ('English', '001', 50, '1st_Term'),
('Mathematics', '001', 40, '1st_Term'),
('French', '001', 60, '1st_Term'),
('English', '001', 60, '2nd_Term'),
('Mathematics', '001', 50, '2nd_Term'),
('French', '001', 50, '2nd_Term'),
('Computer', '001', 70, '2nd_Term'),
('English', '001', 65, '3rd_Term'),
('Mathematics', '001', 60, '3rd_Term'),
('French', '001', 70, '3rd_Term'),
('Computer', '001', 80, '3rd_Term')


SELECT  [SUBJECT],
MAX(CASE WHEN [TERM] = '1st_Term' THEN [SCORE] END) AS '1ST_TERM', 
MAX(CASE WHEN [TERM] = '2nd_Term' THEN [SCORE] END) AS '2ND_TERM', 
MAX(CASE WHEN [TERM] = '3rd_Term' THEN [SCORE] END) AS '3RD_TERM'
FROM #StudentGrades
GROUP BY [SUBJECT]
ORDER BY [SUBJECT]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution but it works. Selecting student, subject and then sub-select for each of the terms. Finally, we `DISTINCT` it because there will be repetitions due to same subject on more than 1 term.

```sql
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    student_id, 
    `subject`, 
    (SELECT score FROM test AS t2 WHERE t2.student_id = t1.student_id AND t1.subject=t2.subject AND t2.term=1) AS term1,
    (SELECT score FROM test AS t2 WHERE t2.student_id = t1.student_id AND t1.subject=t2.subject AND t2.term=2) AS term2,
    (SELECT score FROM test AS t2 WHERE t2.student_id = t1.student_id AND t1.subject=t2.subject AND t2.term=3) AS term3
    
FROM 
    test AS t1
```